# yargs: Require at least one argument without a corresponding flag

Tags: node.js, yargs

I am building a Node CLI app that needs to be passed a single file as an argument.

For example:

```
myapp.js /Users/jdoe/my_file.txt
```

I know I can reference `/Users/jdoe/my_file.txt` through the `_` object in yargs but how do I require that it be provided?  I see the `demandOption()` method but I do not know how to demand options that do not have a corresponding flag (name).

I tried the following and it does not work:

```
.demandOption('_', "A file path is required")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up using `.demandCommand(1)` which works!

Comment: Nice. Who would have thought.

Answer (score 1):

If you're satisfied with yargs and your solution, then by all means continue with what you're doing if you like! I would like to point out some alternatives. There's of course [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) - a well-known cli creator tool. Commander seems to handle required arguments more gracefully than yargs. I have also created a cli creator tool to be (in my opinion) an improvement on the existing tools. The published tool is [wily-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wily-cli), and it should be able to handle what you're wanting to do. For example...

```
const cli = require('wily-cli);

cli
  .parameter('file', true)
  .on('exec', (options, parameters, command) => {
    const file = parameters.file;
    // ...
  });
```

That would cover the example you provided. The `true` flag denotes that the parameter is required. If the parameter isn't provided to the command, it'll display an error saying the parameter is required.

Answer (score 0):

How about this at the top?

```
if (process.argv.length < 3) {
   console.error("A file path is required");
   process.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do this through yargs since I actually have other (optional) options that are available as well.  yargs handles all those just fine and I would like to just configure it for this check as well.